# Is it possible to play an audio file or video file during use of camera

Tags: iphone

As the question says, is it possible to play an overlay video over the camera and record it.

Also, would it be possible to play an audio file while in camera mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can play an audio file while in Camera mode. This is what I do for [Color Collector](http://www.tickletapapps.com/colorcollector). You can record video while having an overlay on the screen, but as far as i know the overlay will not be included in the recorded video.